# Perl not available in Lambda function (with runtime is Node.js 8.10)

Tags: node.js, perl, aws-lambda

I cannot use perl in my lambda function (runtime is Node.js 8.10). Perl previously works fine but now, when I use it, I got an error:

/bin/sh: perl: command not found

I've tried to print "which perl" and I got an error:

`no perl in (/var/lang/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin/:/bin:/opt/bin)`

I've googled any information about changes with perl in aws lambda but I found nothing :(

Here is my code:

```
var exec  = require('child_process').exec;


exports.handleUpload = (event, context, callback) => {
    exec( 'which perl', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        if (error) {console.log(error);}
       console.log(stdout);
      });
    return true;
};
```

Is there any way that I can use perl in my Node JS Lambda function? I can change my runtime and code to python o Golang if needed.

Comment: Perl is not a required component of many distributions; do you know if it was installed?

Comment: @kjpires It was not installed (ouput as when I run `which perl`), but it previously exists :( Is there any way that I can use it? I need perl to use lib `g2ctl`

Comment: Use [perl layer](https://metacpan.org/pod/AWS::Lambda)

Comment: @Lamanus I read this page before but I don't know why I skiped it. My problem was solved by your comment. Thank you very much! You can post an answer and I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a nice article to use perl by using lambda layer.

https://metacpan.org/pod/AWS::Lambda

It keeps following the version update of perl and so it would be very useful.

Comment: But isn't this a custom runtime? What if I only want PERL installed by call it inside Node?